# Is there a scala annotation for null checking?

Tags: scala

I haven't been able to find a scala annotation that uses macros to insert null checks.  This seems to be an obvious use of macros.  What am I missing?

Comment: Don't Java's `@NotNull` and `@Nullable` work?

Comment: That requires using the java compiler (which Scala doesn't use).

Answer (score 8):

You are missing that Scala discourages returning and using `null` and pushes toward using `Option` (`Some`/`None`) instead.

You can read more in [Daniel Westheide excellent overview of the Option type](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html).

Comment: That works for pure Scala code, but as soon as you call some Java library or even the outside world you can get a null.

Comment: You can convert a nullable variable v to Option simply by "Option(v)".  It will returns None if v is null, otherwise Some(v).